# Issue while uploading app to apple store due to ipv6

Tags: ios

I am uploading my app related to chatting to app store but when I am doing this it gets rejected and the apple team gives the following messages -->

1. 2 SAFETY: USER GENERATED CONTENT
2. 1 PERFORMANCE: APP COMPLETENESS

Safety - 1.2

Your app enables users to post content anonymously but does not have the required precautions in place.

Next Steps

Please revise your app to implement all of the following precautions:

- Age rating must reflect 17+.
- Require that users agree to terms (EULA) and these terms must make it clear that there is no tolerance for objectionable content or abusive users.
- A method for filtering objectionable content.
- A mechanism for users to flag objectionable content
- A mechanism for users to block abusive users.
- A mechanism for users to immediately remove post(s) from the feed.
- Developer must act on objectionable content reports within 24 hours by removing the content and ejecting the user who provided the offending content.
- Developer must provide contact information in the app itself, giving users the ability to report inappropriate activity.

Performance - 2.1

Your app crashes on iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.0.2 connected to an IPv6 network when we:

- selected the camera button
- selected the send button

This occurred when your app was used:
- On Wi-Fi

We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Next Steps

Please revise your app and test it on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to ensure that it runs as expected.

I have no idea about this. Please help me to get out of this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the support of IPv6 network, As per Apple guide line, the app submitted after June 1st, 2016 need to support  IPv6. You have to use `NSURLSession` and `CFNetwork` which supports IPv6. [See more here](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a) in the developer site so as to make the App support for IPv6.

And coming to your crash issue, see the crash log provided by Apple and check why is the crash, If it might be due to IPv6 support then it can be resolved by making the App support for IPv6.

For "precautions", that you have mentioned in your question.
You need to put some of the content in your term & condition screen in the App. (just like Age related info as mentioned).

You must have some flag button which will tell the Admin about the offensiveness of message and also there would be some feature to delete the message and user from the App.

Comment: I added the terms and condition page and also using to block the user if someone is sending abusive data. So is it ipv6 related issue ?

Comment: As per the review status, it seems the second one is for IPv6 and the first one is for the user content (taking care of abusiveness, appropriate user). So check both cases, for IPv6 support and user content. If you are saying you added the terms & condition screen. Make sure do you fulfill all scenario mentioned there. If not include them. It is not like only to put those in terms & condition screen you can put it in appropriate place . for eg : If there would be sign up screen you can put information regarding age, but keep in mind Apple rejects if you ask user their Date Of Birth in SignUp.

Comment: ok understood. But please tell me how to fix ipv6 related issue. How to work with ipv6. I don't have any idea.

Comment: What are you using for networking? check if you use NSURLConnection then switch to use NSURLSession instead. If you use AFNetworking library then use the updated method which uses NSURLSession.

Comment: I am using AFNetworking drag and drop library. And i am using AFHTTPSessionManager in it,